# how to bind IsEnabled to property of vm in xaml for button in DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, telerik

I have the button with DataTemplate in my `telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate` xaml.
I want to bind the `IsEnabled` Property in xaml to my prop in viewmodel.
my prop is filled with correct value in viewmodel but didn't show changes in xaml. How to do this?

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
             <Button Content="Edit"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadGridView }},Path=DataContext.SendDateCommand}"
                     CommandParameter="{Binding}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsSetSendDate,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Comment: Is there any binding failure in output window when you debug your program?

Comment: @Mahsa Dehghanpour why do you use the Mode=OneWay, I think it have to be TwoWay...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, changing the Mode to TwoWay for IsEnabled should help. I would also check to ensure that IsSetSendDate is declared as public and has a Getter and Setter in your class. Also make sure that DataContext is set for the xaml, either by declaring with `<Window.Resources>` tag or by setting DataContext in the xaml.cs constructor.